# prevent a form closing with $Form.Close() returning "Cancel"

Tags: winforms, powershell, ps2exe-gui

In my PowerShell script I display a form and I use the `$Form.Close();` command to close it. It closes fine however when it does so it returns the word Cancel *(it also does this if I manually close the form by pressing the top-right red-x)*.

This was OK when I ran the script in the console but now I'm using **PS2EXE-GUI** to run my scripts as a GUI executable when `$Form.Close()` runs a pop-up msg appears with just the word **Cancel** which the user then has to click OK to get rid of. Is there any way to close a form silently please?

[Complete form code on my blog here](https://albarich.wordpress.com/2017/03/31/script-close-form-after-certain-time/)

Comment: I don't work in powershell, but I'd assume you need to set DialogResult to ok. something like: $form.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK

Comment: Hi Troy, Thanks for responding. Your answer looks promising but unfortunately itdoesn't seem to work for me, the result is still "Cancel". Looking at the MSDN page on DialogResult Enumeration it suggests $Form.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::None should work (I don't want any output) but it doesn't - I also tried other options i.e Yes, No OK etc, still only "Cancel" is returned. I can paste my form code below if there's space

Comment: I added $Form.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::None to the section where I define the form - is this the correct location?

Answer (score 1):

I run into this problem today, and I solved it by using the `Out-Null` cmdlet after `ShowDialog` method:

```
$Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do:

```
[void]$Form.Close()
```

But you could also do:

```
$Form.Close() | Out-Null
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I already tried these but they have no effect unfortunately. The scripts runs as before, when the form closes it returns "Cancel"

Comment: @RichieW can you please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43211375/edit) and provide the script, or if it is too long, the main parts of it?

Comment: I've pasted the code here: https://albarich.wordpress.com/2017/03/31/script-close-form-after-certain-time/

Comment: I tried the code and both methods make the closing silent on my computer : ).

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the console to the URL above. When I run the exact code in ISE (or standard console) it opens the form, closes and returns "Cancel". I'm using PS 4 on 8.1, what's your env please?

Comment: In ISE, PS5 on W10. The form does not close by itself here, I have to use Alt + F4 (don't know why, I haven't dived into the code yet).

Answer (score 0):

I found another way of producing the time-limited forms that don't return a DialogResult. I've updated my page [here](https://albarich.wordpress.com/2017/03/31/script-close-form-after-certain-time/) with the updated code.